# Cython with C++ | Compilation error (C++ header not found) | macOS

Tags: python, c++, macos, cython, cythonize

I am trying to implement a very simple C++ code using Cython in macOS. This is the header of my C++ code (it's a file called `cs_test.h`

```
#include<iostream>
void cs_test(int n);
```

This is my C++ code (filename: `cs_test.cpp`:

```
#include "cs_test.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){}

void cs_test(int n)
{
    cout << "This is C++ output: " << n << endl;
}
```

This is my `pyx` code (filename: `simulate.pyx`)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "./cauchy.h" nogil:
void cs_test(int n)

def sim():
    cs_test(5)
```

And, finally, this is my setup code (`setup.py`)

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("simulate.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

All the aforementioned files are in the same folder. I run `setup.py` using this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

And, I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from simulate.c:502:0:
./cauchy.h:1:19: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

In `simulate.pyx`, even when I replace the line `cdef extern from "./cauchy.h" nogil:` with `cdef extern from "cauchy.h" nogil:`, I still get the same error message. I understand that the error message about the use of `gcc` maybe because I am working with macOS. But, I dont know how to let the code know to use `clang++` or `c++` instead.

What am I doing wrong here? I will be very thankful to have help.

Comment: Add a `#include <iostream>` to `cauchy.h`. Or maybe  `#include <iosfwd>`. You will probably need to add  `#include <iostream>` to `cs_test.cpp`. You should probably avoid `using namespace std`. Instead, use `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.

Comment: @jww : I tried `#include <iostream>` . I get the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `language="c++"` in the `setup.py` file (as per the documentation: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py)

Comment: @UnholySheep : The documentation that you had referred me to worked. Presently, I am trying a variant of that and it works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question, rather than just listing technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To make Cython generate and compile C++ code with distutils, you just need to pass the option `language="c++"`:
>
> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> from Cython.Build import cythonize
>
> setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
>        "rect.pyx",                 # our Cython source
>        sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
>        language="c++",             # generate C++ code
>   ))
> ```

This is clearly stated on [the documentation page for using C++ with Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py).

Answer (score 1):

This is the setup file that worked for me. Also I renamed the header file of the C++ code to match the name of the C++ file.

```
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension(
    name="simulate_cy",
    sources=["simulate.pyx", "cs_test.cpp"],
    # extra_objects=["fc.o"],  # if you compile fc.cpp separately
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()],  # .../site-
packages/numpy/core/include
    language="c++",
    # libraries=
    extra_compile_args = ['-O3'],
    # extra_link_args = "...".)
    )]

setup(
    name = 'simulate_cy',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,)
```